# Filtering database depends on Range of cells with regexp

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How i can get range of cells (Result) from my DB depends on another another range (Query), but using regexp, because query data have little differences?
[Look this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GoxANqocmHhtYxovYr3ezDxp1J--LRiv6Ul89cDDwpM/edit#gid=0)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps?

```
=filter(A2:A; regexmatch(A2:A; textjoin("|"; 1; B:B)))
```

or, with query()

```
=query(A2:A; "where A matches '.*("&textjoin("|"; 1; B2:B)&").*'";0)
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)
- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)